# Selenium find by xpath inside Webelement

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have this page:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 1</h1>
            <li class="links">
                <ul><a href="link.com/1"></a></ul>
                <ul><a href="link.com/2"></a></ul>
                <ul><a href="link.com/3"></a></ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 2</h1>
            <li class="links">
                <ul><a href="link.com/4"></a></ul>
                <ul><a href="link.com/5"></a></ul>
                <ul><a href="link.com/6"></a></ul>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <h1>Section 3</h1>
            <li class="links">
                <ul><a href="link.com/7"></a></ul>
                <ul><a href="link.com/8"></a></ul>
                <ul><a href="link.com/9"></a></ul>
            </li>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want group links by sections:

```
driver.get("mypage.com")

sections = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section']")
for section in sections:
    section_name = section.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[@class='name']").get_attribute('innerHTML') #This fails

    links = section.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul/a") #This find all links in page, not only links in section
```

The problem, I find a list of elements (WebElement) in all page by xpath, and now I want find by xpath all specific elements inside a element section, not in all page.

What's wrong?

**Edit 1**

This resolve the problem (now the xpath start whit dot . ):
driver.get("mypage.com")

```
sections = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section']")
for section in sections:
    section_name = section.find_element_by_xpath(".//h1[@class='name']").get_attribute('innerHTML') #This fails

    links = section.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul/a") #This find all links in page, not only links in section
```

Here the explanation y found after: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_xpath

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: Also, use this **xpath** instead, the `.` makes sure to find children of current element: `".//h1[@class='name']"`.

Comment: Yes, what PixelEinstein says works. I have to use . to start from the current element

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You can try this:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/h1/following-sibling::li/ul
```

Comment: Actually the example is simplified just to show the fault, but i think that xpath give you a list with all ul elements. I want find all specific elements from another element found previously

Comment: Little confusing.. What is required from this?

Answer (score 0):

might work

```
sections = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section']")
for i, section in enumerate(sections):
    section_name = section.text
    links = section.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='section'][%s]//a" % str(i+1))
```