# Robot Framework - Get Child Element from Stored Variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to access a specific child of a stored WebElement using robot framework and python

This is what I've tried so far:

```
${child}= Get WebElement ${var[0]}//td[@class='status']

Where ${var} is a list of tr elements (obtained by using the Get WebElements keyword) and each one has 7 td children
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvDoH.png)

But It gives that no element has been found.

Comment: Can you add the `HTML` or the elements ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just added an image of the HTML

Comment: What does ${var} contain? What does "list of elements" mean? Is it something you got from `Get WebElements` keyword?

Comment: Hello @Pekka, sorry for the late response . Yes, It is a list obtained by using the Get WebElements keyword

Comment: SeleniumLibrary is not designed to mix&match WebElement objects and xpaths. If you need to do it, you have to write your own keywords with Python like [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977255/selenium-find-by-xpath-inside-webelement) I feel the easiest way is to modify XPath locator to contain individual cells.